# How can a browser load the image from this URL?

Tags: command-line, browser, webserver, opera

Please look at the screenshot.

[image]

I got this error when I tried to visit a page. Have a look at the URL. It's local LHOST. 127.0.0.1 ... What? How the image can be fetched from this URL? 127.0.0.1:80. How is it possible to display the image? Does Opera has any private server on my device?

Comment: That is an opera built in error page by the looks of it. The program probably allows itself access to local files if they follow that scheme. It's probably not a web server.

Comment: `How the image can be fetched from this URL? 127.0.0.1:80 ` - Easily - if you're the person who has that web service running on your local computer as well. Of course I don't know *why* any one would do this, but you've asked how! `Does opera has any private server on my device` - the answer is definately maybe

Comment: See more:: [Wikipedia: file URI scheme](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

Answer (score 3):

This is an error page customized by Opera. It retrieves the image using `file://`, so simply is accesing the file system of your device.

If you had a server then it would use `http://` or `https://`.

**localhost* is only a reference to the local file system just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784480/phonegap-display-images-with-the-path-cdvfile-localhost-persistent) example. It is not using port 80.

Comment: So it is clear that it doesn't have a private server for opera.Then how it fetch those images by using file:// Normally those file are stored on my storage.But URL doesn't make any sense
file://127.0.0.1:80 
It also has a port address? Does all apps works in this way?

Comment: `localhost` does not mean `127.0.0.1:80`... you are confused. in this case it means "a folder named localhost"