# What can i do if i'm able to access file:// of a website

Tags: browser, webserver, web, cloud-storage

What can I do if I'm able to access file://Facebook.com. ??
I saw some directories like etc,bin,mnt,media and more. Can I make any changes here? Look the screenshot provided.

[image]

Comment: In the screenshot, you are not looking at remote files, you are looking at your local files on your own machine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a browser load the image from this URL?](https://superuser.com/questions/1216098/how-can-a-browser-load-the-image-from-this-url)

Answer (score 1):

The `file://` scheme will look for files on your local machine.

By requesting `file://facebook.com/` as in the screenshot, you are requesting a folder called `facebook.com` in your browser's current working directory.

If you look at `file:///` (note the tripple slash... **schema**://**path**, where **path** is `/`), you may see such directories and files, but these are local to your machine, and are not from a web server.

There is *no server* in this discussion. Load your favorite text editor and open `/etc/login.sh` - it's the equivalent to navigating to `file:///etc/login.sh` in the browser.

Comment: Then have a look at my other question which is similar  https://superuser.com/questions/1216098/how-can-a-browser-load-the-image-from-this-url

Comment: what are you getting at? they said the same thing...

Comment: K..I can access all files. Which means it's not the website's. If yes, what's this <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByT6jPVzn9QQN2E3QmFqWVJXczg/view?usp=drivesdk">Image 1 </img> <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByT6jPVzn9QQcEZBNHNEbmNudG8/view?usp=drivesdk">image 2</img>

Comment: Yep... they are from _your_ computer/tablet/phone. There is _no server_ in this discussion. Load your favorite text editor and open `/etc/login.sh` - it's the equivalent.

Comment: @BenShaji - The images on your google account cannot be access.  Upload to Imgur and provide working links.  The answer remains the same though, your asking about local files, that do not exist outside of your network.

Comment: @Ram The links are working fine 'Attie' is able to access it. The folders will also keep changing according to websites. I can see some Unix system codes. And Apache web files. There are no such directory/files is my device which is damn sure.

Comment: @BenShaji - Well, they didn't work for me, and I can't inline an image from Google Drive into your question on your behalf if you don't do as I requested.

Comment: I still cannot access those files on Google Drive.  You used the `<img>` tag, whcih indicates an image, not a file.  We cannot help you throug the comment section.  *Unnecessary noisy comments will be flag for a moderator to deal with*

Comment: nope... they are 1) a script 2) probably `/bin` 3) definitely `/usr/bin` 4) definitely `/` ... all from your machine

Comment: @Ram here u go,i fixed the broken link. If this is not accessable,try alternative browsers 1-https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByT6jPVzn9QQN2E3QmFqWVJXczg/view?usp=drivesdk%22%3EImage           2-https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByT6jPVzn9QQcEZBNHNEbmNudG8/view?usp=drivesdk%22%3Eimage

Comment: @Ben, no, stop spamming misunderstood images / use an accepted image sharing site

Comment: @BenShaji - The reason I cannot access your Google Drive files is not because of my browser.  Any comments to your Google Files will just be flagged for a moderator to deal with, they are unnecessary, and are just noise at this point.  If you want us to inline images into your question, then we are more then willing to do that, but stop providing us Google Drive files alright?

Comment: Okay. I will next time. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: @Attie, doesn't find longin.sh in the file system of my device.